# How to create a pdf from docx template python?

Tags: python, pdf, converters

I have a script that works when I generate a docx from docx template. However the pdf is not working, I tried to convert the word to pdf, yet this requires microsoft. And on my linux I don't have this option.
This is the script, please advice what is the best way to convert the word to pdf.

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from docx2pdf import convert

async def generate_template(resume: Resume):
    name = resume.name;
    pdfFile = 'static/cvs/' + name + '.pdf'
    wordFile = 'static/cvs/' + name + '.docx'

    print (resume)
    # Test to create a word from a template.
    tpl = DocxTemplate('../templates/' + resume.templateName +'.docx')

    tpl.render(resume)
    tpl.save(wordFile)
    if resume.templateType == "pdf":
        try:
            print ("Converting word doc to pdf...")

            convert(wordFile, pdfFile)
            return {"success": True, "doc": pdfFile}
        except Exception as e:
            print("Converting failed!")
            return {"error": e}

    return {"success": True, "doc":wordFile}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/396825/convert-docx-to-pdf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396825/convert-docx-to-pdf)

Comment: Thank u, actually it helped much!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

`sudo yum install unoconv`

Step 2: On your python code create this function

```
def convert_to_pdf(path, input_docx):
    time.sleep(3)  # Sleep for 3 seconds
    input_docx = input_docx.replace(" ", "\\ ")
    command = 'cd  ' + path + " && " + 'libreoffice  --headless --convert-to pdf ' + input_docx

    print("running " + command)

    os.system(command)
```